# For which functions is $\sqrt{\int_1^2 f(x)^2*xdx} = 0$ true

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal, orthogonal-polynomials

I have to find all functions for which the following statement is true
$$\sqrt{\int_1^2 f(x)^2*xdx} = 0$$
$f(x)$ can be anything: polynomial, trigonometric, exponential, ...
I know I can leave the square root and I have to find an antiderivative for which $F(2)-F(1) = 0$ is true, but I can't seem to get any further than that... any tips or answers would help a lot!

Comment: $*$ is convolution or $\times$ here?

Comment: Is $f(x)$ assumed to be real function?

Comment: 2*3=6, that's what I meant should I change it to x or keep it *?

Comment: @user yes f(x) is assumed to be a real function.

Comment: Is there a reason for the square root?  Of course, $\sqrt{x}= 0$  if and only if x= 0 so this is exactly the same as $\int_1^2 f(x)^2 xdx= 0$. And since $f(x)^2$ is never negative this is never true.

Comment: You should use "@username" to reply on a comment. Otherwise your reply will be probably never read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x)$ has to be identically zero namely $f(x)=0$., because the integrand of the area-integral $A=\int_{1}^{2} x f^2(x) dx$ is positive definite in $(1,2)$. Hence $A$ cannot be zero and if it is zero then $f(x)=0$.

Comment: So the only correct answer is f(x)=0?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous. For example, you can get $f(x)=0$ everywhere except at $1.5$, where $f(x)=1$.

Answer (score 4):

Observe that $x>0, f(x)^2\ge0$. Therefore for the integral to be $0$ you need $f(x)=0$ [almost everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere) on $[1,2]$.